# How to show this upper half plane quotient is isomorphic is the figure of eight.

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers

Let $H$ be the upper half plane of the complex numbers. Let $L$ be the kernel of the map $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z) \to \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z)$.

It was said that $H/L \simeq P^1(\mathbb C) \setminus \{ 0, 1, \infty \}$. How is this shown?

I understand that $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ acts on the upper half plane and I have investigated that $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z) \simeq S_3$ and that the kernel of that map is the 2x2 matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a \; b \\ c \; d\end{pmatrix}$ with the conditions $a \equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $c \equiv d \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, $ad-bc = 1$.

Comment: Note that $L=\Gamma(2)$ is a principal congruence subgroup. If you search within this topic, you'll easily find it.